# Flash using wrong audio output with Pulseaudio

Tags: arch-linux, audio, adobe-flash

I'm using Arch Linux x86_64 with Gnome and PulseAudio. I have USB speakers, which work for the sounds in system menus and most other applications. But whenever I play Flash videos, they output their sound through the onboard sound card (which usually isn't hooked up to anything). This happens in both Firefox and Chromium. I can't find anything that would let me redirect Flash's audio output to my USB speakers.

The following relevant packages are installed:

```
gnome-media-pulse
gnome-settings-daemon-pulse
libcanberra-pulse
pavucontrol
pulseaudio
pulseaudio-alsa
lib32-libcanberra-pulse
lib32-libpulse
flashplugin
```

Comment: [This](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pulseaudio#Flashplugin_.28x86_64_only.29) might be related. Have you tried it? It would be an "official" solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was to install the `libflashsupport-pulse` package from AUR and restart my computer.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what this package actually does? I'm on slackware, and I can't think of why any glue would be required. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @gamen Apparently Flash is hardcoded to look for certain versions of certain library files. I think what this package does is install a library file that effectively redirects Flash output to pulse.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, one very good source for information on pulseaudio problems is the [perfect setup](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/PerfectSetup) page.

I wonder, do *all* ALSA applications have this problem? For example, if you force, say mplayer to use alsa ("`mplayer -ao alsa ...`") does that go to your USB speakers?

An other perhaps more direct reason for this could be that your flash plugin isn't configured properly. You do this by surfing to the [settings manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) (that link actually leads to it immediately; it's not a screenshot or tutorial); see if the speaker output is configured correctly.

Comment: The perfect setup page had some guidelines on how to set pulse as the default in `/etc/asound.conf` but Arch had already set those up for me. I tested other ALSA applications and they all output to the correct source. I looked at the settings manager, but I didn't see anything about speaker outputs.